# When is the leading slash (/) needed in mod_rewrite patterns?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Here is an example from the Apache documentation for enforcing canonical hostnames:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

What I would like to know is why the /? is needed.  I've tried removing it and everything appears to work the same.  I was under the impression that the pattern part of the rewrite rule was compared against what comes after the slash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The {REQUEST_URI} string starts with a / character. Apache changed
>   regex engines when it changed versions, so Apache version 1 requires
>   the leading slash while Apache 2 forbids it! We can satisfy both
>   versions by making the leading slash optional with the expression ^/?
>   (? is the metacharacter for zero or one of the preceding character).

Source: http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

A few more resources which talk about the leading slash

http://forum.modrewrite.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=4627

and
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/

Comment: But the Apache 2.2 documentation has multiple examples with a leading ^/ .  E.g. the [RewriteCond section](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond) has: `RewriteRule  ^/$                 /homepage.std.html  [L]`.

Is that a documentation bug?

Comment: It turns out (as I just tested) that the leading / (^/) is required, at least in VirtualHost context.  I did not test other contexts.

Answer (score 8):

I recently happened across this issue myself. There is a difference between using `RewriteRule` in the VirtualHost and as part of an .htaccess file. The following rule will match (with a URL like this: `example.com/fruit/apple`) if it appears in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(fruit|fruits)/apple http://newfruitwebsite.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

but will not match in the VirtualHost context. If we check out the [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) we can see that:

> When using the rewrite engine in .htaccess files the per-directory prefix is automatically removed for the RewriteRule pattern matching and automatically added after any relative (not starting with a slash or protocol name) substitution encounters the end of a rule set.

*...but what does this mean?* The above rule would not match the same URL if it was placed into the VirtualHost because it doesn't allow a leading slash (`/`) to be at the start of the string. The [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) go on to say:

> The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching occurs against a string which never has a leading slash. Therefore, a Pattern with ^/ never matches in per-directory context.

*...so if we need a slash for .htaccess and no slash for VirtualHost, how do we modify the pattern?* You guessed it. We need to add `/?` to add the following condition in our regex (where our question mark (`?`) is the quantifier):

- Has between 0 and 1 `/` at the beginning of the string.

Now our URL (`example.com/fruit/apple`) string will match because we are handling the fact that if the rule is in the .htaccess file it will have `0` slashes and if it comes from the virtualHost it will have `1` slashes.

---

Related Reading:

- [Apache Rewrite Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

Answer (score 1):

All I know is that on Apache 2.4 on CentOS 7, the leading slash is required in a VHost but is forbidden in .htaccess

VHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName supersite-cms.example.com

  # Forward cms requests to the subsite
  # Note the RewriteRule syntax is different than in .htaccess :|
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/subsite/admin$ https://subsite-cms.example.com/admin [L,R=307,E]

  # ... do other stuff if not redirected
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^subsite/admin$ https://subsite-cms.example.com/admin [L,R=307]
```

---

Source: The last 5 hours 26 minutes of my life

Comment: You can make the slash optional so that it works in either place:  `RewriteRule ^/?subsite/admin$ https://subsite-cms.example.com/admin [L,R=307,E]`